# How to retrieve the file content for a ContentDocument object?

Tags: apex, soql, attachment, contentdocument

Previously, on Salesforce Classic, when a file was uploaded, it was saved on the Attachment object table. This object had the `Body` field.

On Lightning Experience, however, attachments are stored as Content Documents, a completely different (and arguably more complicated) set of tables.

How can I retrieve the file's body when using Lightning Experience? I mean, through SOQL.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Content tables are considerably more complex than Attachments. The file content is held in the `ContentVersion` object; one `ContentDocument` has one or many versions, as well as an arbitrary number of `ContentDocumentLink` records connecting it to records to which it is shared.

Supposing that you already have the Id of a `ContentDocument` attached to some record or another, you can get the relevant file content in SOQL:

```
SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :myId AND IsLatest = true
```

The [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) object reference may be useful.

If you need to acquire files that are attached to a specific object in Salesforce, you'd need to first perform a query against [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentDocumentLink.htm) and filter upon `LinkedEntityId` with the Id of the record-attached-to. The `ContentDocumentLink` field `ContentDocumentId` will then let you perform the above query against `ContentVersion`.

Comment: Can you serve it via API as well ?

Comment: Hi David, Is the process same for an HTTPGet API (Custom one) to pass on the document to mulesoft ?

Comment: @user2598808 For new questions, please open a new post.

Comment: I am confused on how you retrieve the actual bod, lets say that this new file is a json file and you want to read its content?

Comment: @monza It's the `VersionData` blob field shown above. If it contains a string, you call its `toString()` method.