# How to write to static resource (text file) in Managed package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, static-resources, access

## How to write to a static resource (text file) in a Managed package

In my developer org, I can read and write a static resource file by a visualforce page. I make a managed package of them, then install the managed package into another scratch org, there is no write permission of the static resource file any more. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Static Resources [are not subscriber-editable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm), i.e., cannot be changed in subscriber orgs when installed as part of a managed package.

Static Resources are meant to be just that - static. They are not for dynamic file storage. If your managed package needs to store writeable document blobs you should store them somewhere else, most likely a `ContentDocument`.

Comment: Thanks David, I may put the same file into the ContantDocument. Do I need a specific URL for visualforce page and LWC to access the "ContentDocument" of my file?

Comment: You'd probably want to be [querying and retrieving the content](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215115/how-to-retrieve-the-file-content-for-a-contentdocument-object), but I don't have much insight into your use case.

Comment: Thanks David, Is there a simple example to retrieve the file and write back to the file through a visualforce page and lightning component.

Comment: I've never seen such an example but it's really not complicated; just make sure to read up on the Content data structures