# Can we retrieve ContentDocuments aka Files using ANT migration tool in Salesforce?

Tags: ant, contentdocument

I have been trying to retrieve ContentDocuments/Files

[image]

using the following package.xml in ANT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Sample.xml</members>
        <name>ContentDocument</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

but I receive the following error and I also do not see any retrieved files inside the directory.

```
C:\ANT_HOME\apache-ant-1.10.12\sample>ant retrieveUnpackaged
Buildfile: C:\ANT_HOME\apache-ant-1.10.12\sample\build.xml

retrieveUnpackaged:
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09S7Q00000EjOPFUA3
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Pending
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:retrieve] Retrieve warnings (1):
[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity type: 'ContentDocument' is unknown
[sf:retrieve] Finished request 09S7Q00000EjOPFUA3 successfully.
```

Could someone point me to the correct xml structure ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Files are not stored as metadata in Salesforce. The correct way to retrieve files can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215115/how-to-retrieve-the-file-content-for-a-contentdocument-object)